# how can I do a push to a document in mean stack project?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I have this part of code in my controller, what I want to do is when I do a `"getProject"` in postman `"localhost:3000/project/:id"` in the same screen do a post or a put over it with the params, but when I tried to do the put or post it doesn't save in my project model

I tried with this code but doesn't do that I want

```
function createWork(req, res) {
    var work = new Work();
    var project = new Project();
    var projectId = req.params.id;
    var params = req.body;

    obra.name = params.name;
    obra.oficialName = params.oficialName;
    obra.price = params.price;
    obra.workType= params.workType;
    obra.ubication = params.ubication;

    console.log(params);

    Project.update({"Title":"project"}, {
        $push: {
            "work": {
                "name":'name',
                "oficialName":'oficialName',
                "price":'price',
                "workType":'workType',
                "ubication":'ubication',
            }
        }
    },
    {safe: true, upsert: true},
    function(err, updProject){
        if (err) {
            res.status(404).send({message: 'Error'});
        } else {
            res.status(200).send({project: updProject});
        }
    });
}
```

I have two models, the firstone is "project"

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Work = require('../models/work');

var ProjectsSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    officialName: String,
    price: String,
    startDate: String,
    endDate: String,
    contract: String,
    works: [{ type: Schema.Types.Object, ref: 'Work'}]
});

var Project = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectsSchema);
```

and the second is "work" model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var WorksSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    officialName: String,
    price: String,
    workType: String,
    ubication: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Work', WorksSchema);
```

and I want to do a function in project controller that create and push the "work" data into existing "project"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do that I want, with this code as my controller

```
function createWork(req, res) {
    Project.findByIdAndUpdate((req.params.id), {
        $push: {
            "works": req.body
        }
    },
    function(err, updProject) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(404).send({message: 'Error'});
        } else {
            res.status(200).send({project: updProject});
        }
    });

}
```

and with this as my model

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var WorkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    officialName: String,
    price: String,
    workType: String,
    ubication: String
},{timestamps:true});

var ProjectsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    officialName: String,
    price: String,
    contract: String,
    start: String,
    end: String,
    works: [WorkSchema]
},{timestamps:true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectsSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller.js

```
function createWork(req, res) {

    var newProject = new Project();

    var name = req.body.name;
    var oficialName = req.body.oficialName;
    var price = req.body.price;
    var workType= req.body.workType;
    var ubication = req.body.ubication;

    var dataToPush = {
        name : name,
        officialName : officialName,
        price : price,
        workType : workType,
        ubication : ubication
    }

    newProject.update({"Title":"project"}, {
        $push: {
            "work": dataToPush
        }
    },
    {new : truesafe, safe : true, upsert : true},
    function(err, updProject){
        if (err) {
            res.status(404).send({message: 'Error'});
        } else {
            res.status(200).send({project: updProject});
        }
    });
}
```

Model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var WorkSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name : String,
    officialName : String,
    price : String,
    workType : String,
    ubication : String
},{timestamps:true})

var ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    projectName : String,
    work : [WorkSchema]
},{timestamps:true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('project', ProjectSchema)
```

Comment: it send me an error that said "callback.apply is not a function", so, I got another question if is not a problem hehe, that I want to do, is, I have two models "project" and "work" so project have name, officialName, etc. and the "work" array, so I want to push "work" data into work array in project, thanks, I'll edit my post hehe

Comment: this error might be occurring because of `{upsert:true}` , remove it and execute

Comment: it doesn't push the work, the first I need to do is "create project" so when ia have the project created with all data "name, officialName, price, startDate, endDate, contract, work: [ ]." so after that I need to create a work that saves into works array in project every work that I've created into that project must save into works array

Comment: I've already tried but it doesn't show the work when I get the project